# Непонятный редирект?

Tags: редирект

Всем доброго времени суток!

Люди подскажите в чем может быть проблема - на сайте *http://pgsexpert.ru* при заходе на сайт через объявления рекламных систем или при любых символах типа ?

`_utmsource` или `?_openstat` перебрасывает редиректом на адрес *http://pgsexpert.ru* и посещение не регистрируется и не подменяется номер (calltracking).

Занятно, что сервер при подобных адресах отдает 404 код, но редиректит на главную страницу `index.php`

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: сервер Ваш?

Comment: Да, сервер наш :)

Comment: Смотрите .htaccess или настройки модуля, отвечающего за чпу - скорее всего где-нибудь там. Хотя возможно что это нечто самопальное - что-то не припоминаю, чтобы джумла так категорично отрицала get-параметры.

Comment: в .htaccess нет редиректов на главную (( только с www

Comment: Это может быть связано с отключенной функцией mod_rewrite в модуле ЧПУ?

Comment: Нет, без mod_rewrite просто урлы включают в себя /index.php/. Визуально гет-параметры отклоняются только на главной. Поищите где-нибудь связанную с этим конструкцию. Где-нибудь - это недалеко от места, где прописан редирект с /index.php на /

Comment: Спасибо. Пока не разобрался, но привлек человека)